# Encountered error while consuming partitions (...received incorrect magic number) exception in Flink. How can I solve it?

Tags: akka, apache-flink, flink-streaming

**SOLVED**

Problem was that while security tool scans the flink machines, it sent unexpected message(s) to the flink nodes(machines). To solve that problem just enable SSL/TLS for internal communication.

---

**EDIT**:

I am reading kafka topic with `FlinkKafkaConsumer`object for all 3 nodes.

```java
public KafkaConsumer {
public static <T> FlinkKafkaConsumer<T> getKafkaConsumerForFlink(KafkaTopicNames kafkaTopicName, DeserializationSchema<T> deserializationSchema, Properties properties) {
        FlinkKafkaConsumer<T> consumer = new FlinkKafkaConsumer<>(
                kafkaTopicName.name(),
                deserializationSchema,
                properties);

        consumer.setStartFromLatest();
        return consumer;
    }
}
// Then in the main method:
main() {
FlinkKafkaConsumer<MyObject> consumer = KafkaConsumer.getKafkaConsumerForFlink(KafkaTopicNames.myTopic, new KafkaEntitySerialization<>(MyObject.class), Util.getKafkaBrokerIps(KafkaTopicNames.myTopic));
}
```

Recently I have encountered the following exception stacktrace, I don't know where I should look to solve it. Is there anyone faced with the same issue?

(I am running 3 nodes for the flink cluster, each node has 45gb ram and in the flink configuration I have the following setup : `taskmanager.memory.process.size: 40gb`)

Exception stacktrace:

```java
01:02:38,100 WARN  akka.remote.transport.netty.NettyTransport                   [] - Remote connection to [/10.1.2.3:42488] failed with org.apache.flink.shaded.akka.org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.TooLongFrameException: Adjusted frame length exceeds 10485760: 1195725860 - discarded

01:02:38,098 WARN  akka.remote.transport.netty.NettyTransport                   [] - Remote connection to [/10.1.2.3:36954] failed with org.apache.flink.shaded.akka.org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.TooLongFrameException: Adjusted frame length exceeds 10485760: 1195725860 - discarded

01:02:46,085 ERROR org.apache.flink.runtime.io.network.netty.PartitionRequestQueue [] - Encountered error while consuming partitions
org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.unix.Errors$NativeIoException: readAddress(..) failed: Connection reset by peer

01:02:46,210 ERROR org.apache.flink.runtime.io.network.netty.PartitionRequestQueue [] - Encountered error while consuming partitions
org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.handler.codec.DecoderException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Network stream corrupted: received incorrect magic number.
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:471) ~[flink-dist_2.11-1.13.2.jar:1.13.2]
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:276) ~[flink-dist_2.11-1.13.2.jar:1.13.2]
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) [flink-dist_2.11-1.13.2.jar:1.13.2]
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) [flink-dist_2.11-1.13.2.jar:1.13.2]
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357) [flink-dist_2.11-1.13.2.jar:1.13.2]
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410) [flink-dist_2.11-1.13.2.jar:1.13.2]
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) [flink-dist_2.11-1.13.2.jar:1.13.2]
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) [flink-dist_2.11-1.13.2.jar:1.13.2]
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919) [flink-dist_2.11-1.13.2.jar:1.13.2]
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollStreamChannel$EpollStreamUnsafe.epollInReady(AbstractEpollStreamChannel.java:792) [flink-dist_2.11-1.13.2.jar:1.13.2]
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.processReady(EpollEventLoop.java:475) [flink-dist_2.11-1.13.2.jar:1.13.2]
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:378) [flink-dist_2.11-1.13.2.jar:1.13.2]
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989) [flink-dist_2.11-1.13.2.jar:1.13.2]
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) [flink-dist_2.11-1.13.2.jar:1.13.2]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) [?:?]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Network stream corrupted: received incorrect magic number.
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.io.network.netty.NettyMessage$NettyMessageDecoder.decode(NettyMessage.java:210) ~[flink-dist_2.11-1.13.2.jar:1.13.2]
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.handler.codec.LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder.decode(LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder.java:332) ~[flink-dist_2.11-1.13.2.jar:1.13.2]
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:501) ~[flink-dist_2.11-1.13.2.jar:1.13.2]
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:440) ~[flink-dist_2.11-1.13.2.jar:1.13.2]
    ... 14 more


ERROR akka.actor.OneForOneStrategy                                 [] - Error while decoding incoming Akka PDU of length: 64
akka.remote.transport.AkkaProtocolException: Error while decoding incoming Akka PDU of length: 64
Caused by: akka.remote.transport.PduCodecException: Decoding PDU failed.
at akka.remote.transport.AkkaPduProtobufCodec$.decodePdu(AkkaPduCodec.scala:174) ~[flink-dist_2.11-1.13.2.jar:1.13.2]
    at akka.remote.transport.ProtocolStateActor.akka$remote$transport$ProtocolStateActor$$decodePdu(AkkaProtocolTransport.scala:658) ~[flink-dist_2.11-1.13.2.jar:1.13.2]
    at akka.remote.transport.ProtocolStateActor$$anonfun$3.applyOrElse(AkkaProtocolTransport.scala:412) ~[flink-dist_2.11-1.13.2.jar:1.13.2]
    at akka.remote.transport.ProtocolStateActor$$anonfun$3.applyOrElse(AkkaProtocolTransport.scala:375) ~[flink-dist_2.11-1.13.2.jar:1.13.2]
    at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:36) ~[flink-dist_2.11-1.13.2.jar:1.13.2]
    at akka.actor.FSM$class.processEvent(FSM.scala:684) ~[flink-dist_2.11-1.13.2.jar:1.13.2]
    at akka.remote.transport.ProtocolStateActor.processEvent(AkkaProtocolTransport.scala:286) ~[flink-dist_2.11-1.13.2.jar:1.13.2]
    at akka.actor.FSM$class.akka$actor$FSM$$processMsg(FSM.scala:678) ~[flink-dist_2.11-1.13.2.jar:1.13.2]
    at akka.actor.FSM$$anonfun$receive$1.applyOrElse(FSM.scala:672) ~[flink-dist_2.11-1.13.2.jar:1.13.2]
    at akka.actor.Actor$class.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:517) ~[flink-dist_2.11-1.13.2.jar:1.13.2]
    at akka.remote.transport.ProtocolStateActor.aroundReceive(AkkaProtocolTransport.scala:286) ~[flink-dist_2.11-1.13.2.jar:1.13.2]
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:592) ~[flink-dist_2.11-1.13.2.jar:1.13.2]
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:561) ~[flink-dist_2.11-1.13.2.jar:1.13.2]
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:258) ~[flink-dist_2.11-1.13.2.jar:1.13.2]
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:225) ~[flink-dist_2.11-1.13.2.jar:1.13.2]
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.exec(Mailbox.scala:235) ~[flink-dist_2.11-1.13.2.jar:1.13.2]
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260) ~[flink-dist_2.11-1.13.2.jar:1.13.2]
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339) ~[flink-dist_2.11-1.13.2.jar:1.13.2]
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979) ~[flink-dist_2.11-1.13.2.jar:1.13.2]
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107) ~[flink-dist_2.11-1.13.2.jar:1.13.2]
Caused by: akka.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException: Protocol message contained an invalid tag (zero).
    at akka.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException.invalidTag(InvalidProtocolBufferException.java:93) ~[flink-dist_2.11-1.13.2.jar:1.13.2]
    at akka.protobuf.CodedInputStream.readTag(CodedInputStream.java:112) ~[flink-dist_2.11-1.13.2.jar:1.13.2]
    at akka.remote.WireFormats$AkkaProtocolMessage.<init>(WireFormats.java:8964) ~[flink-dist_2.11-1.13.2.jar:1.13.2]
    at akka.remote.WireFormats$AkkaProtocolMessage.<init>(WireFormats.java:8928) ~[flink-dist_2.11-1.13.2.jar:1.13.2]
    at akka.remote.WireFormats$AkkaProtocolMessage$1.parsePartialFrom(WireFormats.java:9024) ~[flink-dist_2.11-1.13.2.jar:1.13.2]
    at akka.remote.WireFormats$AkkaProtocolMessage$1.parsePartialFrom(WireFormats.java:9019) ~[flink-dist_2.11-1.13.2.jar:1.13.2]
    at akka.protobuf.AbstractParser.parsePartialFrom(AbstractParser.java:145) ~[flink-dist_2.11-1.13.2.jar:1.13.2]
    at akka.protobuf.AbstractParser.parseFrom(AbstractParser.java:181) ~[flink-dist_2.11-1.13.2.jar:1.13.2]
    at akka.protobuf.AbstractParser.parseFrom(AbstractParser.java:192) ~[flink-dist_2.11-1.13.2.jar:1.13.2]
    at akka.protobuf.AbstractParser.parseFrom(AbstractParser.java:197) ~[flink-dist_2.11-1.13.2.jar:1.13.2]
    at akka.protobuf.AbstractParser.parseFrom(AbstractParser.java:53) ~[flink-dist_2.11-1.13.2.jar:1.13.2]
    at akka.remote.WireFormats$AkkaProtocolMessage.parseFrom(WireFormats.java:9142) ~[flink-dist_2.11-1.13.2.jar:1.13.2]
    at akka.remote.transport.AkkaPduProtobufCodec$.decodePdu(AkkaPduCodec.scala:175) ~[flink-dist_2.11-1.13.2.jar:1.13.2]
    at akka.remote.transport.ProtocolStateActor.akka$remote$transport$ProtocolStateActor$$decodePdu(AkkaProtocolTransport.scala:658) ~[flink-dist_2.11-1.13.2.jar:1.13.2]
    at akka.remote.transport.ProtocolStateActor$$anonfun$3.applyOrElse(AkkaProtocolTransport.scala:412) ~[flink-dist_2.11-1.13.2.jar:1.13.2]
    at akka.remote.transport.ProtocolStateActor$$anonfun$3.applyOrElse(AkkaProtocolTransport.scala:375) ~[flink-dist_2.11-1.13.2.jar:1.13.2]
    at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:36) ~[flink-dist_2.11-1.13.2.jar:1.13.2]
    at akka.actor.FSM$class.processEvent(FSM.scala:684) ~[flink-dist_2.11-1.13.2.jar:1.13.2]
    at akka.remote.transport.ProtocolStateActor.processEvent(AkkaProtocolTransport.scala:286) ~[flink-dist_2.11-1.13.2.jar:1.13.2]
    at akka.actor.FSM$class.akka$actor$FSM$$processMsg(FSM.scala:678) ~[flink-dist_2.11-1.13.2.jar:1.13.2]
    at akka.actor.FSM$$anonfun$receive$1.applyOrElse(FSM.scala:672) ~[flink-dist_2.11-1.13.2.jar:1.13.2]
    at akka.actor.Actor$class.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:517) ~[flink-dist_2.11-1.13.2.jar:1.13.2]
    at akka.remote.transport.ProtocolStateActor.aroundReceive(AkkaProtocolTransport.scala:286) ~[flink-dist_2.11-1.13.2.jar:1.13.2]
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:592) ~[flink-dist_2.11-1.13.2.jar:1.13.2]
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:561) ~[flink-dist_2.11-1.13.2.jar:1.13.2]
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:258) ~[flink-dist_2.11-1.13.2.jar:1.13.2]
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:225) ~[flink-dist_2.11-1.13.2.jar:1.13.2]
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.exec(Mailbox.scala:235) ~[flink-dist_2.11-1.13.2.jar:1.13.2]
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260) ~[flink-dist_2.11-1.13.2.jar:1.13.2]
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339) ~[flink-dist_2.11-1.13.2.jar:1.13.2]
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979) ~[flink-dist_2.11-1.13.2.jar:1.13.2]
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107) ~[flink-dist_2.11-1.13.2.jar:1.13.2]

01:02:46,241 ERROR org.apache.flink.runtime.io.network.netty.PartitionRequestQueue [] - Encountered error while consuming partitions
org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.handler.codec.DecoderException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Network stream corrupted: received incorrect magic number.
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:471) ~[flink-dist_2.11-1.13.2.jar:1.13.2]
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:276) ~[flink-dist_2.11-1.13.2.jar:1.13.2]
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) [flink-dist_2.11-1.13.2.jar:1.13.2]
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) [flink-dist_2.11-1.13.2.jar:1.13.2]
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357) [flink-dist_2.11-1.13.2.jar:1.13.2]
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410) [flink-dist_2.11-1.13.2.jar:1.13.2]
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) [flink-dist_2.11-1.13.2.jar:1.13.2]
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) [flink-dist_2.11-1.13.2.jar:1.13.2]
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919) [flink-dist_2.11-1.13.2.jar:1.13.2]
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollStreamChannel$EpollStreamUnsafe.epollInReady(AbstractEpollStreamChannel.java:792) [flink-dist_2.11-1.13.2.jar:1.13.2]
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.processReady(EpollEventLoop.java:475) [flink-dist_2.11-1.13.2.jar:1.13.2]
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:378) [flink-dist_2.11-1.13.2.jar:1.13.2]
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989) [flink-dist_2.11-1.13.2.jar:1.13.2]
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) [flink-dist_2.11-1.13.2.jar:1.13.2]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) [?:?]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Network stream corrupted: received incorrect magic number.
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.io.network.netty.NettyMessage$NettyMessageDecoder.decode(NettyMessage.java:210) ~[flink-dist_2.11-1.13.2.jar:1.13.2]
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.handler.codec.LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder.decode(LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder.java:332) ~[flink-dist_2.11-1.13.2.jar:1.13.2]
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:501) ~[flink-dist_2.11-1.13.2.jar:1.13.2]
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:440) ~[flink-dist_2.11-1.13.2.jar:1.13.2]
    ... 14 more
```

Comment: I think the error is happening when "Flink is talking to itself", like, when serializing events from one task manager to another due to a shuffle or something like that. The error `Protocol message contained an invalid tag (zero)` suggest the sender and the receiver disagree on the what the schema of that Protobuf should be. Could it be that that schema has been updated at some point somehow? Or that one part of the app is using Confluent schema registry serializer and the other not? Is the app using Flink custom Kryo serializer for protobuf?

Comment: Hi @Svend, for schema you means kafka entity serialization rigth? I am using FlinkKafkaConsumer object to do that (I just update my question, see EDIT section). Also what can you say about NettyTransport warning ip address 10.1.2.3 was not belong to the flink cluster, this is a security ip address looking for vulnerabilities on the opening port(s)

Comment: Hi. My best guess is that the issue above is not related to `FlinkKafkaConsumer`. Flink relies on serialization for 2 broad purposes: interacting with external storages (e.g. with sth like `FlinkKafkaConsumer`), or when shuffling data internally within the Flink cluster. The fact that the stack-trace involve `akka` trying to deserialize a protobuf (cf `akka.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException: Protocol message contained an invalid tag`) makes think this is very probably failing during such kind of internal serialization (unrelated to Kafka)

Comment: I understood what you mean. But the problem is that, I didn't apply anything related to protocol (even i never touched it and i have no idea how to change it as well), and i don't know where i should look to resolve this issue. My only guess is that it is related to the ip address 10.1.2.3. Thank you ...